# Unable to alter database table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add a new column in table so i am running following mysql command.

```
alter table student add doe datetime not null default curdate();
```

But it says I have error in mysql statement near curdate();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your query as below.

```
ALTER TABLE `student` ADD `doe` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

it should solve your answer.

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because you can't use function as default value.

Answer (score 0):

It is available from MySQL version 5.6.5. Check this: 
http://optimize-this.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/datetime-default-now-finally-available.html

Previous versions can deal with timestamp type:

```
ALTER TABLE student ADD doe TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:
**alter table student add doe datetime not null default now();**